# Are Firefox Sync settings device specific?

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync

I'm using Firefox Sync on several hosts, but I want not all of them to snyc their Add-Ons and settings. However unchecking these option in Sync does not work, after some times, they are checked again.

So, do Firefox Sync settings apply to the account as a whole (or ALL devices), or are the specific for a device? Anyone knows?

Comment: I believe it's for the account as a whole, but I don't know how it decides which machine/host is the "master", if an option is checked on one, but not on another. Maybe check their website?

Comment: I went through [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org) but did not find any relevant information.